# Результат запроса содержит в себе одну строку, вместо двух

Tags: php, sql, запрос

Пытаюсь вывести из БД информацию о нескольких квартирах следующим запросом, он конечно длинный, но (мне кажется, особое внимание стоит обратить на условие IN):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT flats.*, sort.value as sort, 
street.name as street, district.name as district, type.name as type,
underground.name as underground, `line`.name 
as `line` FROM flats join sort 
on flats.sort=sort.id_sort join district on 
flats.district=district.id_district join street 
on street.id_street=flats.street join underground 
on underground.id_underground=
flats.underground join type on 
type.id_type=flats.type join `line` on `line`.id_line=underground.line 
where id in (:id)"); $stmt->execute(array('id' => $str));
```

В $str записываются два-три числа, в phpMyAdmin проверяю - все верно, выводит нужное кол-во строк. А потом я пытаюсь вывести это на самом сайте и получаю массив, который содержит следующее:

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[id] => 1 
[sort] => Студия 
[district] => Чертаново Южное 
[street] => Варшавское шоссе 
[underground] => Динамо 
[jk] => 
[floorf] => 5 
[numb] => 1 
[floorh] => 17 
[elevator] => 2 
[type] => Панельный 
[rooms] => 2 
[floor] => 1 
[price] => 5000000.99 
[size] => 50.00 
[bathroom] => 1 
[balcony] => 1 
[img] => 1q.jpg 
[popular] => 1 
[enabled] => 1 
[created_at] => 2016-10-21 22:41:50 
[updated_at] => 
[line] => Замоскворецкая линия ) )
```

Содержит в итоге информацию только об одной квартире.

Вывожу следующим образом:
$res = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($res);

Что я делаю не так, куда пропадает вторая?

Comment: нельзя в IN передать массив. к параметру привязывается всегда только одно значение. надо что то типа `id in(?,?,?)` (кол-во вопросов равно количеству передаваемых id) и `execute(explode(',',$str))`

Comment: либо один раз prepare() sql-запрос и несколько раз execute()

Comment: а генерируемый SQL запрос вы проверяли после подстановки параметров?

Comment: Я передаю в параметр строку "1,2"
Просто у меня когда как, может передаваться 2 параметра, а может 3, if писать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из документации

> Нельзя привязать несколько значений к одному параметру; например, нельзя привязать два значения к именованному параметру в выражении IN().
>
> Нельзя привязать больше значений, чем заявлено в запросе; если в массиве input_parameters больше элементов, чем заявлено в SQL запросе методом PDO::prepare(), выполнение запроса завершится неудачей, и будет вызвана ошибка.

Вот код для решения Вашей задачи

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
$values = [1, 2, 3];
$params = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params), '?'));
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ... id IN ($params)");
if (!$stmt) {
  $err = $pdo->errorInfo();
  die($err[2]);
}
if (!$stmt->execute($values))
  $err = $stmt->errorInfo();
  die($err[2]);
}
```